# How to implement a left recursion eliminator?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, topdown

How can i implement an eliminator for this?

```
 A := AB |
      AC |
      D  |
      E  ;
```

Comment: hi Mahdi i am  new and interested what are u trying?can  u explain me

Comment: i am trying to build a parser, which takes the grammar and checks to see if there is any left recursion or left factoring. if so then tries to eliminate them so that it can work with an ll(1) grammar.the whole thing is about transforming an ll(k) to ll(1) grammar.

Comment: ll(k) grammars must not contain left recursion because a left recursive rule in a ll(k) parser will send it into an infinite recursive call exactly the same way as it will do with ll(1). Also ll(k) is more powerful than ll(1) so that you can't transform any ll(k) to ll(1).

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of so called *immediate left recursion*, and is removed like this:

```
A := DA' |
     EA' ;

A' := ε   |
      BA' |
      CA' ;
```

The basic idea is to first note that when parsing an `A` you will necessarily start with a `D` or an `E`. After the `D` or an `E` you will either end (tail is ε) or continue (if we're in a `AB` or `AC` construction).

The actual algorithm works like this:

For any left-recursive production like this: `A -> A a1 | ... | A ak | b1 | b2 | ... | bm` replace the production with `A -> b1 A' | b2 A' | ... | bm A'` and add the production `A' -> ε | a1 A' | ... | ak A'`.

See [Wikipedia: Left Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion) for more information on the elimination algorithm (including elimination of indirect left recursion).

Answer (score 0):

Another form available is:

```
A := (D | E) (B | C)*
```

The mechanics of doing it are about the same but some parsers might handle that form better. Also consider what it will take to munge the action rules along with the grammar its self; the other form requires the factoring tool to generate a new type for the `A'` rule to return where as this form doesn't.