# Converting a grammar to LL(1)

Tags: parsing, grammar, recursive-descent

I have this grammar:

```
program ::= expr_list

expr_list ::= {LF} [expr {LF {LF} expr}] {LF}

lvalue ::= [expr DOT] NAME

call_param ::= [[NAME COLON] expr {COMMA [NAME COLON] expr}]

func_param ::= [NAME [COLON expr] {COMMA NAME [COLON expr]}]

expr ::= lvalue
       | lvalue ASSIGN expr
       | expr OPAREN call_param CPAREN
       | FUNC func_param LF expr_list END
       | IF expr LF expr_list {ELSEIF expr LF expr_list} [ELSE expr_list] ENDIF
       | WHILE expr LF expr_list LOOP
       | DO expr_list LOOP WHILE expr LF
       | INTEGER
```

I partially wrote a recursive descent parser:

```
void Parser::ntProgram()
{
    ntExprList();
}

void Parser::ntExprList()
{
    // ???
}

void Parser::ntLvalue()
{
    // ???
}

void Parser::ntCallParam()
{
    // ???
}

void Parser::ntFuncParam()
{
    if (accept(Lexer::NameTok)) {
        if (accept(Lexer::ColonTok)) {
            ntExpr();
        }
    }
    while (accept(Lexer::CommaTok)) {
        expect(Lexer::NameTok);
        if (accept(Lexer::ColonTok)) {
            ntExpr();
        }
    }
}

void Parser::ntExpr()
{
    if (accept(Lexer::FuncTok))
    {
        ntFuncParam();
        expect(Lexer::LfTok);
        ntExprList();
        expect(Lexer::EndTok);
    }
    else if (accept(Lexer::WhileTok))
    {
        ntExpr();
        expect(Lexer::LfTok);
        ntExprList();
        expect(Lexer::LoopTok);
    }
    else if (accept(Lexer::DoTok))
    {
        ntExprList();
        expect(Lexer::WhileTok);
        expect(Lexer::LoopTok);
        ntExpr();
        expect(Lexer::LfTok);
    }
    else if (accept(Lexer::IfTok))
    {
        ntExpr();
        expect(Lexer::LfTok);
        ntExprList();
        while (accept(Lexer::ElseifTok))
        {
            ntExpr();
            expect(Lexer::LfTok);
            ntExprList();
        }
        if (accept(Lexer::ElseTok))
        {
            ntExprList();
        }
        expect(Lexer::EndifTok);
    }
    else if (accept(Lexer::IntegerTok))
    {
    }
}
```

But I don't know what to do in some parts, for example the way that an expr can be an lvalue, whose first item could be an expr.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to parse the expr rule, you have to eliminate left recursion first. This is well explained on Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion

Comment: Here are some left recursion references on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036021/how-to-implement-a-left-recursion-eliminator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425977/how-to-remove-left-recursive-in-this-antlr-grammer

Comment: I've only seen guides to removing immediate left recursion in things like math expressions, where there is a more limited form of expression on one side. But in the function call rule, the first "expr" really should match any kind of expr, even other function calls, while loops, etc.